# Querying SharePoint XML data by GUID in PowerShell

Tags: xml, sharepoint, powershell, migration

I have a large XML file. It contains my SharePoint 2010 migration-check logs (we are getting ready for a 07 to 10 migration). I am interested in the sections that show where all the missing webparts are, specifically their URLs. I have been trying to identify the associated site URL with each guid the PS SP10 tools found to be a problem. I am relatively new to Powershell and was curious if there is a simple way to get the data?

```
get-childitem R:\testfile.xml | select-string -pattern "c7843aae-4c86-8206-0125-d00117cb461c"
```

Returns each instance, such as: 
testfile.xml:112644:  
However, I need the URL associated with the webpart.

```
$xml.databases.Database[1].Site[0].Webs.Web
```

(this is the same as testfile)
is the level that stores this information (gives me ID, URL, LanguageId,TemplateName,TemplateId,Features,EventRecieverAssemblies,WebParts,CustomListViews,SetupFiles).

Is there a way to combine these commands? I just need to find each instance of that guid, and its associated website's URL. Thanks for any help, I am new to PowerShell and figured it might be able to help me go through this document without going (that gui's instance shows up about 85 times) by hand.

Thank you so much. Also, long time lurker, first time poster.

Nick

```
    <Databases>
  <Database SiteCount="2" Name="WSS_Content" DataSource="xxx">
    <Site Id="ef5d110e-3562-4e4f-bdf4-0ee688e92701" OwnerLogin="xxxx" InSiteMap="True">
      <Webs Count="1">
        <Web Id="eb0591b4-0ccd-4834-8f97-abe9974b8a32" Url="site/xxxxxxa" LanguageId="1033" TemplateName="xxx#0" TemplateId="10001">
          <Features>
            <Feature Id="00bfea71-c796-4402-9f2f-0eb9a6e71b18" Count="1" DisplayName="WebPageLibrary" InstallPath="C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\Template\Features\WebPageLibrary" Status="Installed" />
          </Features>
          <EventReceiverAssemblies>
            <EventReceiverAssembly Name="Microsoft.Office.InfoPath.Server, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" Status="Installed" />
          </EventReceiverAssemblies>
          <WebParts>
            <WebPart Id="ce9aa113-48cf-ddee-0c03-597445e5b7ab" Count="1" Status="Installed" Type="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ImageWebPart" />
            <WebPart Id="293e8d0e-486f-e21e-40e3-75bfb77202de" Count="35" Status="Installed" Type="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ListFormWebPart" />
            <WebPart Id="2242cce6-491a-657a-c8ee-b10a2a993eda" Count="35" Status="Installed" Type="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ListViewWebPart" />
          </WebParts>
          <CustomListViews />
          <SetupFiles>
            <SetupFile Path="C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\Template\1033\STS\doctemp\word\wdtmpl.doc" Count="3" Status="Installed" />
            <SetupFile Path="C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\Template\Features\BasicWebParts\MSContentEditor.dwp" Count="1" Status="Installed" />
          </SetupFiles>
        </Web>
      </Webs>
    </Site>
    <Site Id="389fa2ac-4b8a-4704-ad98-e49619c981a0" OwnerLogin="xxx\srv-xxx" InSiteMap="True">
      <Webs Count="2">
        <Web Id="3820015a-56cf-41b8-9607-bbed7775f514" Url="/site/xxxxx" LanguageId="1033" TemplateName="OSRV#0" TemplateId="40">
          <Features>
            <Feature Id="00bfea71-5932-4f9c-ad71-1557e5751100" Count="1" DisplayName="IssuesList" InstallPath="C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\Template\Features\IssuesList" Status="Installed" />
          </Features>
          <EventReceiverAssemblies>
            <EventReceiverAssembly Name="Microsoft.Office.InfoPath.Server, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" Status="Installed" />
            <EventReceiverAssembly Name="Microsoft.Office.Server, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" Status="Installed" />
          </EventReceiverAssemblies>
          <WebParts>
            <WebPart Id="d55b3b6b-6281-707b-73d0-0c49581475ad" Count="1" Status="Installed" Type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.SearchStatsWebPart" />
            <WebPart Id="6172b769-e922-1e5e-b706-1073173cbce3" Count="1" Status="Installed" Type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.CompletedCrawls" />
            <WebPart Id="bc0158dd-a329-57ce-3563-1afacb17ec6c" Count="1" Status="Installed" Type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.SystemStatus" />
            <WebPart Id="f5c3ff60-e752-3a90-84f8-3677f8384e2d" Count="2" Status="Installed" Type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.CoreResultsWebPart" />
            <WebPart Id="f2c50a02-9894-4ace-bb3f-4146a24cd940" Count="2" Status="Installed" Type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.SearchPagingWebPart" />
            <WebPart Id="c54a0f4e-d855-ad45-ef85-4e67abf15a4d" Count="1" Status="Installed" Type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.ActiveCrawls" />
            <WebPart Id="e60f6c95-e86c-4717-2c0d-6d8563c9caf7" Count="1" Status="Installed" Type="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ContentEditorWebPart" />
            <WebPart Id="293e8d0e-486f-e21e-40e3-75bfb77202de" Count="29" Status="Installed" Type="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ListFormWebPart" />
            <WebPart Id="2242cce6-491a-657a-c8ee-b10a2a993eda" Count="19" Status="Installed" Type="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ListViewWebPart" />
            <WebPart Id="74bd016c-baa0-14a8-d5d8-b75dc7e6f429" Count="1" Status="Installed" Type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.ContactFieldControl" />
            <WebPart Id="fb35a198-aea0-3c26-e40c-df473fe9b07b" Count="2" Status="Installed" Type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.HighConfidenceWebPart" />
            <WebPart Id="669602d9-e116-ccb8-eea3-e37ad589b14b" Count="1" Status="Installed" Type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.SearchSummaryWebPart" />
            <WebPart Id="f5897322-ddd4-c990-d012-f9d4fe2180ad" Count="2" Status="Installed" Type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.SearchBoxEx" />
          </WebParts>
          <CustomListViews />
          <SetupFiles>
            <SetupFile Path="C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\Template\1033\STS\doctemp\word\wdtmpl.doc" Count="2" Status="Installed" />
          </SetupFiles>
        </Web>
        <Web Id="d2e7ca33-fc74-4907-a34f-4c5ae1dbde84" Url="/ssp/admin/xxxxa" LanguageId="1033" TemplateName="PROFILES#0" TemplateId="51">
          <Features>
            <Feature Id="00bfea71-c796-4402-9f2f-0eb9a6e71b18" Count="1" DisplayName="WebPageLibrary" InstallPath="C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\Template\Features\WebPageLibrary" Status="Installed" />
          </Features>
          <EventReceiverAssemblies />
          <WebParts>
            <WebPart Id="293e8d0e-486f-e21e-40e3-75bfb77202de" Count="6" Status="Installed" Type="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ListFormWebPart" />
            <WebPart Id="2242cce6-491a-657a-c8ee-b10a2a993eda" Count="5" Status="Installed" Type="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ListViewWebPart" />
            <WebPart Id="f6bfd4dd-e6b5-7cb0-e080-e7674fcdd856" Count="1" Status="Installed" Type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.BusinessDataDetailsWebPart" />
          </WebParts>
          <CustomListViews />
          <SetupFiles>
            <SetupFile Path="C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\Template\1033\STS\doctemp\word\wdtmpl.doc" Count="1" Status="Installed" />
          </SetupFiles>
        </Web>
      </Webs>
    </Site>
  </Database>
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the xml that you are using?

Comment: Sure this is the file structure of the xml
`<Databases>
  <Database>
   <Site>
    <Webs>
     <Web> (this level contains the site URL)
      <Features>
       <Feature>
      <WebParts>
       <WebPart> (this level has the ID used to Identify the part)`
  
 If you want to see actual code let me know, I must have a file host  somewhere. Thanks for your help

Comment: Edit your question and attach a concrete xml, maybe from testfile.xml ( not like what you have above). Relevant code would be helpful too

Comment: Added some of the testfile.xml, edited out some of the info to fit into here. Thanks so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$xml.SelectNodes("//Web") | %{ 
    if($_.SelectNodes("./WebParts/WebPart") | ?{ $_.id -eq "f6bfd4dd-e6b5-7cb0-e080-e7674fcdd856" } ){
        $_.Url
    }
}
```

Here, I am looking for guid `f6bfd4dd-e6b5-7cb0-e080-e7674fcdd856` and it returns `/ssp/admin/xxxxa`, the url of the Web

Comment: Wow, that worked beautifully. Thank you so much. Really made my day.

Comment: is it possible to also grab the count? I have tried this using your code but cannot seem to grab them both together. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

you can use this proxy-function

```
Function Get-Content {
<#
***************************************************************************

 --------------------8<-----------------------------------------
    Ajout de deux nouveaux paramètres pour simplifier
    le traitement des fichiers XML: [-AsXml] [-XPath <String>]

    Attention: l'expression Xpath est sEnSiBlE à La cAsSe

                                  Walid toumi             
 --------------------8<-----------------------------------------

 PS> # Exemples d'utilisation:

 PS> $file = "$PSHOME\types.ps1xml"

 PS> $u = cat $file -As | Select-Xml -XP "//ScriptProperty" | Select -Expand Node
 PS> $u

 PS> $Xml = Get-Content $file -AsXml
 PS> $Xml.Types.Type[1..10]

 PS> Get-Content $file -AsXml -XPath "//Type[contains(Name,'Xml')]/Name"

 **************************************************************************

.ForwardHelpTargetName Get-Content
.ForwardHelpCategory Cmdlet

#>

[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='Path', SupportsTransactions=$true)]
param(
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [System.Int64]
    ${ReadCount},

    [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [System.Int64]
    ${TotalCount},

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Path', Mandatory=$true, Position=0, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [System.String[]]
    ${Path},

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='LiteralPath', Mandatory=$true, Position=0, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [Alias('PSPath')]
    [System.String[]]
    ${LiteralPath},

    [System.String]
    ${Filter},

    [System.String[]]
    ${Include},

    [System.String[]]
    ${Exclude},

    [System.String]
    ${XPath},

    [Switch]
    ${Force},

    [Switch]
    ${AsXml},

    [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]
    ${Credential})

begin
{
    try {
        $outBuffer = $null
        if ($PSBoundParameters.TryGetValue('OutBuffer', [ref]$outBuffer))
        {
            $PSBoundParameters['OutBuffer'] = 1
        }
        $wrappedCmd = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.GetCommand('Microsoft.PowerShell.Management\Get-Content', [System.Management.Automation.CommandTypes]::Cmdlet)
        $cmd = ''
         if($AsXml) {
          [void]$PSBoundParameters.Remove('AsXml')
          $cmd += ' | ForEach-Object {$fx=@()} {$fx+=$_} {$fx -as [Xml]}'
            if($XPath) {
               [void]$PSBoundParameters.Remove('XPath')
               $cmd += ' | Select-Xml -XPath $XPath | Select -expand Node'
            }
        } 
        $ScriptCmd = [ScriptBlock]::Create(
           { & $wrappedCmd @PSBoundParameters }.ToString() + $Cmd
          )
        $steppablePipeline = $scriptCmd.GetSteppablePipeline($myInvocation.CommandOrigin)
        $steppablePipeline.Begin($PSCmdlet)
    } catch {
        throw
    }
}

process
{
    try {
        $steppablePipeline.Process($_)
    } catch {
        throw
    }
}

end
{
    try {
        $steppablePipeline.End()
    } catch {
        throw
    }
}

}
```

like this:

```
$file = "file.xml"
Get-Content $file -AsXml -XPath "//Web[WebParts/WebPart//@*[1][contains(.,'f6bfd4dd-e6b5-7cb0-e080-e7674fcdd856')]]/@*[2]"
```

or simply

```
Select-Xml -Path $file -XPath '//Web[WebParts/WebPart/@Id = "f6bfd4dd-e6b5-7cb0-e080-e7674fcdd856"]/@Url' | % { $_.node.'#text' }
```

Comment: Thank you! Curious, if I wanted to grab the associated count attribute as well, so I get back the URL and the Count, how could I do that? I am finding XML and powershell difficult to learn. Thank you both so much for your time and help